# OpenStreetMap - Overpass API; geometry disappears from node when using center

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api

Here's my query

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “building”
  way["building"]({{bbox}});
  relation["building"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out center ids tags geom ;

>;
out skel qt;
```

If I use `center` then `geom` values are not shown. I want to output `center` and `geom`. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two separate output commands:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  way["building"]({{bbox}});
  relation["building"]({{bbox}});
);
out geom;
out center ids;  // use ids to only get the centerpoint without nodes & tags
```

Comment: Yes. It does give you center and geom information but too much redundant information.

Comment: @NinjaMAN - I updated my answer to use "out center ids" instead of "out center".  This removes duplicated nodes and tags, but it will still output two elements - maybe good enough?   
Note that since the "out" only supports one output format at a time, I'm not sure there's a way to get both the full geometry and the center into one single element with the json output.